# Rotate SVG element in Internet Explorer or Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation, transform, microsoft-edge

I am animating an SVG object with different elements, everything is working okay except for transform rotation in Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge.
Is there any way I can still rotate the SVG element **without** taking it out the SVG object.

I tried:

- CSS Animations on the SVG element using ID
- Adding transform rotate using Javascript

> With SVG object I refer to raw SVG pasted into my HTML page, no
>   `<object>` element.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The example would be a simple SVG element with an ID, try to make it rotate, no example required.

Comment: @Joost Code is actually required for questions like this, per site rules.

Comment: Okay Ill try to add some code later, currently busy. My apologises if I broke the rules.